# Enable auto sign-in on Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, login, auto-login

It's tedious to type my password every time I start my Windows 10 VM, especially since you can't paste a password into the box. I want to set up automatic login.

Following the instructions [here](http://www.windows10forums.com/threads/how-to-disable-login-screen-on-win-10.165/) I tried to disable the "Users must enter a user name and password" option in `netplwiz`. But **the option isn't there**! It should be above the "users for this computer" list. Is there a setting I need to change to allow me to change the setting?

[image]

Comment: Weird. For me, this option is there. Win 10 Prof. Maybe it has to do with permissions, because yours shows Administrators; ... Your guide and also in my netplwiz, it just shows Administrators

Comment: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-security/checkbox-does-not-appear-in-user-accounts-netplwiz/2d83d8d4-88b3-484a-941c-b69e68f774dd?auth=1

Comment: ^ follow that to see if you can make appear the checkbox

Comment: @malarres I don't see "Reset Security Policies" in the control panel either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was because my VM was part of a domain (an *organization* in Windows 10 parlance). Removing the machine from the domain ("disconnecting from the organization") made the checkbox reappear and allowed me to enable auto-login.

Answer (score 7):

ok, if you make the following modification to your registry the option will be available again in netplwiz. Default setting is 2.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\PasswordLess\Device]
"DevicePasswordLessBuildVersion"=dword:00000000
```

`0` = on
`2` = off

Answer (score 3):

You can use [**Autologon.exe**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autologon) (Sysinternals tool) or using registry keys:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon]
"AutoAdminLogon"="1"
"DefaultDomainName"="DOMAINNAME"
"DefaultUserName"="USERNAME"
"DefaultPassword"="PASSWORD"
```

Extracted from: http://www.sysadmit.com/2016/01/windows-configurar-autologin.html

Answer (score -1):

MS removed this option in one of their latest builds (2004 I think).  It seems based on my research if you have done clean an install with a new ISO it will not display this option.  However if you did an upgrade it you will still have this option.

Comment: This is absolutely false.  Microsoft doesn’t go to the effort of making changes to the UI if you have performed a “clean install” or an “upgrade”.  In reality there isn’t a difference between those two methods of installing Windows.