# Power on by rtc and put user pass on win 10 automatically

Tags: windows-10, rtcwake

I would like my pc to power on automatically every day at a specific time.
I know how to do this in BIOS. The problem is that when the pc is booted, it requires a password to log in on windows.
The question is: How do I get my pc to login with my password automatically?

Thanks.

Clarification: What I want is to keep my account locked with a password. I don't want to disable my password in order to login automatically. The automation that I want, is to have a password, but inserted and log in automatically when my pc boots up automatically through rtc boot from bios.

Clarification 2: I don't want to disable my password universally. What I want is to still have my password active and inserted automatically when my pc boots automatically through rtc from bios. When I boot it up myself, I want it to ask me for the password.

Comment: My question is different, please see my clarification above.

Comment: If you follow the advice in the duplicate you will see that you are not removing the password, you are simply enabling automatic login. I'm still not clear how you believe this to be distinct.

Comment: If you want to have it automatically log in, load Windows and **then** lock your machine to prevent others using it, then that would be distinct, but is not what you are asking currently. Otherwise you need to be clear about exactly what you expect to be the outcome of this, as currently the duplicate *is* answering what you are asking.

Comment: This [answer](http://superuser.com/a/1047746/213131) is what you're looking for. It doesn't involve removing the password from your account.  And it's the *only* way to accomplish auto-login without a 3rd-party utility.

Comment: Maybe I have not made myself that clear. Please see clarification 2 in my edited answer. What you both suggest disables my pass every time my pc is booted, regardless if it boots automatically or by myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest way to do this is:

1)Disable your user account password (run--->"netplwiz")

2)Use your BIOS settings to setup "boot by rtc"

3)With task scheduler, make a task that runs after every boot, which will run a program that locks your pc. Make sure to delay this by a few seconds.

So in a way, your pc will boot without password, but with the help of task scheduler, it will lock itself almost immediately after every boot.