# How do I enable automatic login in Windows 10 Pro with a local account?

Tags: windows-10, user-accounts, login, auto-login

I have Windows 10 Pro computer with a local non-microsoft Admin Account. How can I enable it to login automatically at boot time? The corresponding checkbox in netplwiz isn't visible.

[image]

Comment: Please provide a screenshot.  There should absolutely be a checkbox.

Comment: @Ramhound I added the screenshot. I read that the checkbox may disappear when using Windows Hello or Pin login, but I'm using neither. This is a fresh and fully updated install, no microsoft account, no pin or Windows Hello, just a single user.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Enable auto sign-in on Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/1047623/enable-auto-sign-in-on-windows-10)

Answer (score 1):

Go to Settings > Accounts > Work Access. If you have access with work place, the "Users must enter a user name and password to use this computer" option won't appear.

Comment: I don't have work access set up.

Comment: If you are using a Microsoft account, go to Settings > Accounts > Sign-in options. Toggle the button under "Require Windows Hello sign-in for Microsoft accounts" Off. Restart Windows 10 to apply the changes. Then you should see the checkbox "Users must enter a username and password to login" in netplwiz.

Answer (score 0):

In order to make the checkbox appear, you need to first remove your PIN (or face/fingerprint/security key if applicable)

go to Settings > Account > Sign In Options

select "Windows Hello PIN" and then click remove.

Then run netplwiz again and the checkbox should be visible.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I can't test it anymore so I can't accept an answer at this time.