# How to enable automatic login on Windows 11 RTM with a local user account?

Tags: login, windows-11, auto-login, autologon

How can you enable automatic login on Windows 11 RTM (Build `22000.282`)?

I've been trying to configure a Windows 11 Pro for Workstations VM running on HyperV to automatically login on boot.

I don't have a Microsoft account associated; only a local administrator account and the VM is not domain joined. I have not configured a Windows Hello Pin.

I tried all three approaches in [this article](https://winaero.com/windows-11-sign-in-automatically-without-a-password/) without success.

1. `netplwiz` was not showing the key checkbox for me initially. Via the Registry hack [here](https://superuser.com/a/1568128/75791) I managed to get the `netplwiz` dialog to behave correctly, but when I reboot the VM it leaves me at the login screen.
2. `AutoLogon64` claims to have configured automatic login, but upon reboot behavior is unchanged.
3. Setting the registry keys manually also yields no results.

I suspect this article was tested against the preview versions of Windows 11, so I'm seeking information on how to enable autologin with the RTM build.

Comment: run command ControlUserPasswords2

Comment: @Moab not found: https://imgur.com/JiFH3Gd

Comment: Tried it with a Space (Control UserPasswords2) and it took me to the same netplwiz dialog. I did it again anyway (unchecked and rechecked the box) and the behavior of the system is unchanged.